# Left Align of Text using CSS

Tags: css, text-alignment

Here is the problem, I have a single-page application where I lay out a form:

[image: Imgur]

Due to my novice CSS skill, I have not been able to left align the help text (in blue). Here is my HTML code:

```css
label {
  width: 15%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

span.short_help {
  font-size: 70%;
  color: cornflowerblue;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <label for="Authentication">Authentication:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Authentication" id="-Authentication" />
    <span class="short_help">Authentication type, I, II, or III</span>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <div>
    <label for="Branch">Branch:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Branch" id="Branch" />
    <span class="short_help">Which regional branch.</span>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <div>
    <label for="Persistent">Persistent:</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Persistent" id="Persistent" />
    <span class="short_help">Persistent connection</span>
  </div>
  <br/>
</form>
```

If I fixed up the input field to make the controls the same width so the help text align, then the check box will be centered:

[image: Imgur]

Here is what I added to the CSS above:

```
input {
    width: 15%;
}
```

How can I have both the controls and the blue text left aligned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of setting a *width* on all *input* fields, wrap a `div` arround it with a *class*. In my example *.input*

Now you can set the *width* of the field without affecting the `input` width.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

form {
  max-width: 600px;
}

label, .input, span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-left: -4px;
}

label {
  width: 20%;
}

.input {
  width: 30%;
}

span {
  color: cornflowerblue;
}
```

```html
<form>
    <div>
        <label for="Authentication">Authentication:</label>
        <div class="input">
          <input type="text" name="Authentication" id="-Authentication" />
        </div>
        <span class="short_help">Authentication type, I, II, or III</span>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div>
        <label for="Branch">Branch:</label>
        <div class="input">
          <input type="text" name="Branch" id="Branch" />
        </div>
        <span class="short_help">Which regional branch.</span>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div>
        <label for="Persistent">Persistent:</label>
        <div class="input">
          <input type="checkbox" name="Persistent" id="Persistent" />
        </div>
        <span class="short_help">Persistent connection</span>
    </div>
    <br/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an element to wrap around the inputs and make them the desired size:

```
<div>
    <label for="Authentication">Authentication:</label>
    <span class="spacer">
        <input type="text" name="Authentication" id="-Authentication" />
    </span>
    <span class="short_help">Authentication type, I, II, or III</span>
</div>
<br/>
<div>
    <label for="Branch">Branch:</label>
    <span class="spacer">
        <input type="text" name="Branch" id="Branch" />
    </span>
    <span class="short_help">Which regional branch.</span>
</div>
<br/>
<div>
    <label for="Persistent">Persistent:</label>
    <span class="spacer">
        <input type="checkbox" name="Persistent" id="Persistent" />
    </span>
    <span class="short_help">Persistent connection</span>
</div>
```

And add CSS to format it:

```
span.spacer {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 15%;
}
```

Comment: It does not work. The form looks worse than before. https://jsfiddle.net/3uu4L2qj/

Comment: It does look bad in the fiddle, but when pasted together in an independent document, it looks like what you're asking for--though the percentage widths can cause overlapping if the window isn't wide enough.

Comment: I apologize and took back what I said. I tried it outside of fiddle and it it is a good solution. +1

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite get it, do you only want to align the checkbox or the blue text

To align the checkbox to the left, change

```
 input {
        width: 15%;
    }
```

to

```
input[type="text"] {
    width: 15%;
}
```

Comment: It does not work. The text still not align https://jsfiddle.net/ayk14p91/1/

Answer (score 0):

the input driver you can align your text to the left so

```
input
{
text-align: left;
width: 15%;

}
```

but the tag span can not be proque is an online element for more doubt read this site that talks about the span tag:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span

You can also contain the span in a div and somehow achieve alignment